# About the benefit of objectWithID:

Tags: ios, core-data

The doc says:

> If the object is not registered in the context, it may be fetched or
>   returned as a fault. This method always returns an object. The data in
>   the persistent store represented by objectID is assumed to exist—if it
>   does not, the returned object throws an exception when you access any
>   property (that is, when the fault is fired). The benefit of this
>   behavior is that it allows you to create and use faults, then create
>   the underlying data later or in a separate context.

I'm thinking about the last sentence:

> The benefit of this behavior is that it allows you to create and use faults, then create the underlying data later or in a separate context.

Does it mean I can use `objectWithID:` with an arbitrary `ID` to get a fault handle of an non-existing object first then later create the object with `ID`? But how can I assign an arbitrary `ID` to the new object?

Comment: What happens if you save the object you received?

Comment: You can save normally, but it does not make sense. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Yes you can get a handle to a non existing item an later create that item.
But, since you don't know what ID will be assigned to the item these is not very useful in that case.

You could use `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` to obtain the object final ID, but, this is a trip to the store, and will have a performance penalty.

You can use `objectWithID:` to "warm up" the coordinator cache. in this manner you may fetch objects in the background, and use this method in another context then access these items without hitting the store (much better performance).

Comment: I don't think "you can get a handle to a non existing item an later create that item" in any meaningful way. Please see my own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20938757/56149

Comment: you're doing it wrong an0 ;) he mentions explicitly `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` --- delete & re-insert = new ID. BTW: He said it isn't useful too

Comment: @Daij-Djan How do you interpret "create the underlying data later"? If you already have the object and obtain ID from the object you create the data first not later.

Comment: fill the objects attributes and relationships way after getting the ID.. not yet saving the object because maybe it won't get filled... e.g. when parsing a file

Answer (score 0):

Since every `NSManagedObjectID` must initially come from a fulfilled `NSManagedObject` and there is no way to create one from scratch, the only possible way to "create the underlying data later" is meaningless, as follows:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objID = object.objectID;
[moc deleteObject:object];
…
object = [moc objectWithID:objID]; // Deleted so non-existing
[moc insertObject:object]; // Kinda of resurrecting the deleted object, but not really since the data are gone only ID is left. So it is creating a new object with the old ID. But what's the point?
// Fill data into object
…
[moc save:NULL];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use `-objectWithID:`, it will return a fault **if** the object is not already registered in the managed object context (ie. only if the object hasn't already been fetched and hasn't been faulted in). In the case that it does return a fault, you do not need to do anything to "create the object". Simply accessing the attributes of the object will automatically fire the fault and let you access its data. There is no additional work needed on your part to create additional objects.

Comment: No what I asked. Please read the question again. Also you can read my own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20938757/56149

Comment: unrelated to question